# Java Collections with Mutable Objects

Tags: java, list, collections, mutable

How does a TreeSet, HashSet or LinkedHashSet behave when the objects are mutable? I cannot imagine that they would work in any sense?

If I modify an object after I have added it; what is the behaviour of the list?

Is there a better option for dealing with a collection of mutable objects (which I need to sort/index/etc) other than a linked list or an array and simply iterating through them each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface addresses this issue directly: "Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element."

Addendum:

> Is there a better option for dealing with a collection of mutable objects?

When trying to decide which collection implementation is most suitable, it may be worth looking over the [*core collection interfaces*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html). For [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementations in particular, as long as `equals()` and `hashCode()` are implemented correctly, any unrelated attributes may be mutable. By analogy with a database relation, any attribute may change, but the primary key must be inviolate.

Answer (score 2):

Being mutable is only a problem for the collection if the objects' hashCode and behaviour of compare methods change after it is inserted.

The way you could handle this is to remove the objects from the collection and re-adding them after such a change so that the object.

In essence this results in a inmutable object from the collections' point of view.

Another less performant way could be to keep a set containing all objects and creating a TreeSet/HashSet when you need the set to be sorted or indexed. This is no real solution for a situation where the objects change constantly and you need map access at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to deal with this situation is to keep ancillary data structures for lookup, a bit like indexes in a database. Then all of your modifications need to make sure the indexes are updated. Good examples would be maps or multimaps - before an update, remove the entry from any indexes, and then after an update add them back in with the new values. Obviously this needs care with concurrency etc.